# Ordnance Survey layer not supported in the Offline version of ArcGIS Online map

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, ordnance-survey, arcgis-online-webmap

I use the Ordnance Survey maps API for my ArcGIS Online project. Everything works well, as the maps are very wealthy in detail and can be used down to the highest zoom level. It's simply great. The problem arises in the situation when I want to make my map used offline. I simply cannot with the OS layer.
I typed everything correctly ( I mean the WMTS link -> Key) and made it available for my map.
When it comes to the Offline section I see, that this particular layer isn't supported.
[image]

I tried also with Road_3857 and it's the same.

The only alternative, which would resemble the OSGB maps is the built-in GB Cartographic basemap in ArcGIS Online. Unfortunately, it's far too general for the project I do. The difference between them two is staggering.

[image]

Comment: I would say you need to be talking to OS about this.

Comment: I've already raised an "Error", although in fact, it's hard to say that it's an error itself as the maps work well.

Comment: believe this is a due to a digital license difference when you want it 'offline' it is like copying the data  (disclaimer not a lawyer) reach out to Ordnance Survey https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/licensing.

Comment: Good point. I thought about this either.